# Specify "--build_python_zip" flag within Bazel py_binary rule

Tags: bazel

Is it possible to specify the bazel "--build_python_zip" flag from within the py_binary rule so that I don't need to add this flag every time I use Bazel in my workspace?

Answer (score 2):

After [PR 9453](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/pull/9453), you can:

```
filegroup(
    name = "foo_zip",
    srcs = [":foo_binary"],
    output_group = "python_zip_file",
)

py_binary(
    name = "foo_binary",
    srcs = ["foo.py"],
)
```

Then you can invoke bazel as:

```
bazel build :foo_zip
```

and don't have to specify `--build_python_zip`. This will also allow `par_binary` rules to co-exist with native zips.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem that there's a way to specify this per `py_binary` target, [according to this issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3530).

However, you can use a `bazelrc` file to store common options. Add the following line to your workspace's `bazelrc` at `<workspace>/.bazelrc`:

```
build --build_python_zip
```

Note that using this method, every invocation of `bazel build`, `bazel test` and `bazel run` will include this flag.